# can I link library except specific symbol?

Tags: assembly, x86, linker, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

***Condition 1.***  I have `myassembly.s` which do not have `main`.

***Condition 2.***  Instead, `myassembly.s` have *global symbol* `_start`.

***Condition 3.***  I wanna link `_IO_stdin_used` to output binary.

...and here is problematic part.
`_IO_stdin_used` is asserted on `crt1.o` as you can see :

```
jiwon@jiwon:/tmp$ readelf -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 17 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     ...
     8: 00000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 _fp_hw
     9: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_csu_fini
    10: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 _start
    11: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_csu_init
    12: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND main
    13: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT    6 data_start
    14: 00000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    5 _IO_stdin_used
    15: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main
    16: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    6 __data_start
```

***Question.***  Can I link `crt1.o` without `_start`?


~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


...

*I attach my situation more specifically as it may be information needed for analysis.*

*Here is `myassembly.s`.*
*As aforementioned situation, It use `_start` and don't have `main`.*

```
.global _start
_start:
 push $_STRING1
 push $_STRING2
 call printf
 push $0
 call exit
_STRING1:
 .string "gogo\n"
_STRING2:
 .string "%s"
```

*I assemble and linked it :*

```
jiwon@jiwon:/tmp$ as -o stackoverflow.o stackoverflow.s 
jiwon@jiwon:/tmp$ ld -o stackoverflow -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crti.o -lc stackoverflow.o /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o

jiwon@jiwon:/tmp$ ./stackoverflow 
gogo
```

*As you can see above, the output binary works well.*
*However, when I tried `crt1.o` to be linked, the error happens.*

```
jiwon@jiwon:/tmp$ ld -o stackoverflow -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crti.o -lc stackoverflow.o /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
stackoverflow.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_init'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
```

***Question (Same)***  Can I link `crt1.o` without `_start`?

Comment: Even if you would bend the tools to do that, you should not, because the `crt1` with skipped `_start` code will be in unstable/undefined state at runtime. One option is to follow the original design and produce only `main` in your code and let `crt1` do the startup initialization and calling you later as `main`. Other option is to produce different app entry than `_start`, modify linker script to use your "start2" as entry point, and call `_start` from crt1 on your own, at moment you deem appropriate (but before using crt1 functionality). (but make sure you understand crt1 init completely)

Comment: I think it might be much more fruitful to request `_IO_stdin_used` in your own assembly file than trying to link in `crt1.o`.

Comment: hm, didn't read it into details, but now I think fuz's is more on point.

Comment: This looks like http://xyproblem.info/. What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: @Ped7g Thank you for the advice! I tried followed your second option, but `crt1.o` muttered about absence of `main` : *"In function '_start', undefined reference to 'main', "* And due to my assembly file does not have `main`, It seems to be difficult to apply this method :(..

Comment: then provide the `main` ... I mean, if you need some kind of "main", then you can reuse it straight away, if you don't need main, then you can provide empty function (but then I'm not sure, if the crt1 will not run main + get exit from main + de-initialize everything... so maybe you will need main sleeping indefinitely to not return from it - maybe wait for some signal from other code ...  if your main functionality is working in other thread independently from classic C `main`)

Comment: I mean, for me it's not clear, what is your goal. If you want classic "hello world" like console application, then there's no reason to not use `main` as your app entry point and let the clib do all the dirty init work (and put your app code into `main`). If you are doing some low level things and you surely do NOT want to use `main` as entry point (weird, but what do I know, maybe you have good reason), then you may either provide the fake sleeping `main` for crt1, or dissect crt1 sources and initialize it on your own (and providing fake empty `main` just for linking purposes).

Comment: and as your example shows `call printf` from the clib, you probably want to have your code in ordinary `main`, as you are actively using the I/O streams by that call. Avoiding the common path of: `crt1::_start` -> `main` ending with `return <status_code>;` -> `crt1` will do cleanup and finish - makes little sense to me. Are you sure you want to avoid the common C-way of doing things, yet you want also to use clib for I/O? That sounds complicated, and I wouldn't bother, unless you have some good reason.

Comment: @Ped7g Thank you for your thoughtful answer!  Here is why I cannot use `main` in assembly: I'm developing some tools for generating `reassembleable disassembly`. ([Here](https://seclab.cs.ucsb.edu/media/uploads/papers/ramblr-ndss17.pdf) is paper about existing work.) The `myassembly.s` that I mentioned above was generated by disassembling `mybinary` (To simplify the question, I omited lots of lines of it). Because `mybinary` was a striped binary, I could not determine any symbols(including `main`) except for the `_start`, which is the entry point information that cannot be stripped.

Comment: ok, that sounds like good reason, but that means it will get complicated... will? It already did. I'm too busy to read+think more about it, so I don't have more advice for you at this moment, but take then my original advice in the limited way, addressing more common use-cases, you have a bit more special case.

Comment: @Ped7g Ok. Again, thank you for your nice advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pulling in the whole rat's tail of `crt1.o`, how about you simply define `_IO_stdin_used` yourself?  Just put this code in one of your assembly files:

```
        .section .rodata
        .globl _IO_stdin_used
        .type _IO_stdin_used, @object
        .align 4
_IO_stdin_used:
        .int 0x20001
        .size _IO_stdin_used, 4
```

Otherwise, if you just want to require the presence of `_IO_stdin_used` without defining it yourself (for example, because some file in the libc defines it), just put this line into one of your assembly files:

```
        .globl _IO_stdin_used
```

This causes the assembler to mark `_IO_stdin_used` as an undefined global symbol which the linker has to pull in from somewhere.

Comment: I didn't know that I could declare library's symbol on my code before reading your answer! Thank you very much.